# How can i use javascript to sort the tables by column? Can not use jquery here. I'm using javascript to load a table from an xml file

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
<div id="banner1"; class="float1">
<form>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="noOption">Select a table to view</option>
<option value="StudentHistory">StudentHistory</option>
</select>
<br><br>
</form>
```

Using javascript the select option opens the student history table.  How do I run a script on the table that loads to sort the columns of the table alphabetically or numerically.

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///C:/Users/Jordan/Documents/development/data0001.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 




function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
//  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " +  x ;}

if (x == "noOption") {document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Please make a proper selection" ;}
else if (x == "StudentHistory") {

var stable;
stable = "";


stable  +="<table><tr><th>personID</th><th>firstname</th><th>mid</th><th>last</th><th>age</th><th>sex</th></tr>";
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PersonInform");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  stable  +="<tr><td>";
  stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("personID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  stable  +="</td><td>";
  stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
stable  +="</td><td>";
  stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("mid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
stable  +="</td><td>";
  stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("last")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  stable  +="</td><td>";
  stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
stable  +="</td><td>";
stable  +=x[i].getElementsByTagName("sex")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
stable  +="</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = stable;
  }
  }
 </script>
```

The stable table object has 6 columns which I would like to be able to sort alphabetically.  Any suggestions? Can't use jquery.  Can use JSON or javascript.

```
<p id="test" onchange="myFunction()"> </p>

</div>


<div id="footer">
```

Let me know if you' would like to see the whole code. Thank you StackOverflow.

Comment: ANYTHING you can do in jQuery, you can also do in plain JS... so don't think of not using jQuery as a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain javascript function that sorts a table.  It assumes that the first row of the table contains `<th>` tags and that clicking on one of those means the table should be sorted by that column.  The function guesses whether to do a numeric or text sort based on the content of the columns.  It also keeps track of the previous sort in a column and if clicking multiple times in the same header column, it will reverse the sort.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6Ldxdqbb/

```
function makeTableSortable(tableSelector) {
    var columnHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(tableSelector + " th");
    for (var i = 0; i < columnHeaders.length; i++) {
        columnHeaders[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // column header was clicked, get the column number
            var row = closest(this, "tr");
            var headers = Array.prototype.slice.call(row.querySelectorAll("th"));
            var columnNumber = headers.indexOf(this);
            var cells, columnData = [], data, textCnt = 0, numberCnt = 0, parent;

            // now get the data to sort
            var table = closest(this, "table");
            var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                cells =  rows[i].querySelectorAll("td");
                data = cells[columnNumber].textContent;
                // if it starts with numbers, mark it for numbers
                if (data.match(/^\s*\d+/)) {
                    data = parseInt(data, 10);
                    ++numberCnt;
                } else if (!data.match(/\s*/)) {
                    ++textCnt;
                }
                columnData.push({rowElement: rows[i], rowNum: i, data: data});
            }
            // we now have all columnData and can sort it
            if (numberCnt > textCnt) {
                columnData.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.data - b.data;
                });
            } else {
                columnData.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.data.localeCompare(b.data);
                });
            }
            // if sorting the same column we last sorted, then reverse the prior
            // sort order
            if (table._lastSortColumn === columnNumber) {
                if (table._lastSortDirection === "increasing") {
                    // reverse our current sort
                    columnData.reverse();
                    table._lastSortDirection = "decreasing";
                } else {
                    table._lastSortDirection = "increasing";
                }
            } else {
                table._lastSortDirection = "increasing";
            }
            table._lastSortColumn = columnNumber;
            // now we have the sorted data and we need to just rearrange the rows into the desired order
            parent = rows[0].parentNode;
            for (i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {
                parent.insertBefore(columnData[i].rowElement, null)
            }
        });
    }

    function closest(start, tag) {
        tag = tag.toLowerCase();
        while (start && start !== document.documentElement && start.tagName.toLowerCase() !== tag) {
            start = start.parentNode;
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

Comment: @usjavabc - does this give you an idea how to do this?

Comment: this is very useful - but since i'm still at the basic level  - this seems very advanced and complex for my currrent intellect - i thank you for taking the time to answer the question though.

Comment: @USjavabc - that's what it takes to sort a table by column in plain Javascript.  You should be able to study the code and learn/understand what it's doing.  You can ask questions about things you don't understand.