# Sorting, element.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data; JavaScript, Table

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

//Solved
I am trying to navigate trough a DOM tree and sort the elements.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>El</td>
<td>B</td> <---------Take this as a criterion
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El</td>
<td>A</td> <------------- same
</tr>
</table>


var compare=function(x, y) {
    var xValue=x.innerHTML;
    var yValue=y.innerHTML;
    if(xValue==yValue) return 0;
    else if(xValue>yValue) return 1;    
    else return -1; 
}
```

...
   And my algorithm:

1. Push the `getElementsByTagName("tr")` in an array row_tab
2. Array with the same content
   ...

   ```
   var row_t=new Array();
             for(i=0;i<row_tab.length;i++){
                 row_t[i]=row_tab[i]; //2.
             }

       var cattosort=new Array(); //Array for the second td-elements
       for(i=0;i<row_tab.length; i++){
           cattosort[i]=row_tab[i].firstChild.nextSibling;
       }    
             cattosort=cattosort.sort(compare);

         for(i=0;i<cattosort.length; i++){
             for(var k=0; k<row_t.length; k++){
           if(cattosort[i].firstChild.data==row_t[k].firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data){ 
   //Here should be the mistake in the navigation,but formal it
   //seems true for me (row_t[k].firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data->
   //the text of the next sibling of the first child->the text of the 2. element    

          z=row_tab[i];
          row_tab[i]=row_t[k];
          row_t[k]=z;
       }
         } 
         }
   ```

However, there is no error, but my programme doesn't react. Do I use the proper command /element.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data->(see the comments under the if in the code)/?

PS: I'm not permitted to use libraries, if that matters.

Comment: This is your homework, right?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve in your question.  Are you trying to "sort the rows of a table by the content in a specific column in that table"?  If so, please put that near the top of your question.  If not, then please describe exactly what the task is in your question.

Comment: @ThomasLandauer Yes,thats why I cant use libraries, however, im not asking someone to write it, Im asking for a concrete command, in my case element.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data; and I`m allowed to do this

Comment: Where is your `compare()` function?  What does it do? And, please describe what you're trying to do in your third `for` loop after the `cattosort.sort()`

Comment: @jfriend00 compare is for the sorting, so with cattosort.sort(...) I sort the array, in which I first copied the content, that needs to be sorted; in my last for-loops I make this: for all elements in the array cattosort{   check in which position k in the not sorted array is the element, thats on position i in the sorted array, move the element k in position i->element k sorted... and so for every element

Comment: I know `compare` is part of the sort.  I was asking to see the code for that since it could be part of your problem.  Your scheme of putting things in sorted order (your last `for` loop) looks like is has all sorts of problems.  A common algorithm for sorting things like this is to get the data and a reference to the object that contains it, sort the data, then reinsert all the elements in sorted order, one after another.  This moves the elements around rather than reassigns data.  This can work just fine for a table as long as the object you reinsert is the containing row.

Comment: Various demos of sorting DOM elements or tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381735/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-sort-the-tables-by-column-can-not-use-jquery-here/29382433#29382433, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622874/sort-table-by-price-column/15623255#15623255, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545960/sort-elements-of-javascript/11546491#11546491

Comment: There are all sorts of problems with your code.  You need to back way up to the beginning and come up with an algorithm for how to do sorting of table rows by a column that will actually work.  We can't really offer incremental advice to "fix" your code because it looks pretty far away from something that would work.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, actually I dont want that somebody fixes it, I only wanted to know if this element.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data really navigates to the second td

Comment: If `element` is a `<tr>` then `element.firstChild.nextSibling` will be the second `<td>` in that row.  I don't know what you're trying to do with `.data`.  Usually, one will get `.innerHTML` or .textContent` to get the contents of an element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way, what I do with .data: <tr><td>some text</td></tr> or any other tag:  td is a child of tr, the text is a child of the child (text-firstChild of the td), so with td.firstChild.data; I become the text, it has the same function as this, that you say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you back up and find a good algorithm for sorting table rows.  Since this appears to be homework, I'm going to suggest the algorithm without giving you the exact code.

The general algorithm I've seen used many times does the following:

1. Build an array of objects where each object in the array contains a row DOM element reference and the content to sort by.
2. Sort that array using a custom sort function.  Since the content is in an object along with the DOM reference to the containing row, this will sort both together.
3. Now that you have a sorted array, simply reinsert the each row into the table one after another in the order of the sorted array.  This moves whole row elements around and does not actually reassign content.

Here's a related example from another answer: [How can i use javascript to sort the tables by column? Can not use jquery here. I'm using javascript to load a table from an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381735/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-sort-the-tables-by-column-can-not-use-jquery-here/29382433#29382433)